# Securing Android traffic from passive listening

Tags: android, security, session, sniffing

I have a question about building an android app to secure my WI-Fi traffic from sniffing.

Is it possible to make app (I think, like, secure browser) that will prevent passive traffic sniffing apps (like DroidSheep) from getting my session id?

Comment: You can encrypt the data being exchanged and can protect your session ID too using SSL. But, you can never stop anyone from seeing your encrypted data, even though they cannot see the underlying data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I think, it'll work fine, if the attacker will see only encrypted data.